Scheduled SuiteScript to load a CSV from File Cabinet and append saved search results to CSV and save
I am attempting to create a historical csv backup (appended rather than overwritten) to our file cabinet using a saved searches results (on a once a week schedule).
I know its possible to write a saved searches results to a CSV (using task), but I'm not sure how I can append instead (maybe using file.appendline?). Here is what I've come up with which results in the appended data being "task.SearchTask" instead of the saved search results:


/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/file', 'N/task'],
    /**
 * @param{file} file
 * @param{task} task
 */
    (file, task) => {

        /**
         * Defines the Scheduled script trigger point.
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Script execution context. Use values from the scriptContext.InvocationType enum.
         * @since 2015.2
         */

        //[file ID, Saved Search ID]
        const keys = [
            [72567, 1701]
        ]

        const execute = (scriptContext) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var searchTask = task.create({
                    taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH,
                    savedsearchId: keys[i][1]
                });

                var csvFile = file.load({
                    id: keys[i][0]
                });

                //This probably doesn't work...
                csvFile.appendLine({
                    value: searchTask
                });

                csvFile.save();
            }
        }

        return {execute}

    });



Any assistance would be appreciated!

The return value of task.create is a task object, and not the results of the saved search object, so returning that to your function won't give you the results you're after.
Here's how I might tackle this one to append data from a search to a file. Now that NetSuite supports higher versions of EcmaScript, I prefer const over var and using for ... of loops over standard for loops for better readability and less thinking about state.
Beware that there are some file size and governance limitations that you could run into if your files/searches are too big, so be careful. Be sure to test everything thoroughly.

/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define([
  'N/search',
  'N/file',
], (search, file) => {

const execute = (): void => {
   // I prefer arrays of objects over arrays of arrays for readability, but you could change these to arrays if you needed
   const searchesToProcess = [
      { searchId: 456, fileId: 123 },
      { searchId: 9876, fileId: 124 },
   ]

   for (const search of searchesToProcess) {
      appendSearchResultsToFile({ searchId: search.searchId, fileId: search.fileId });
   }

};

const appendSearchResultsToFile = ({ 
   searchId, 
   fileId,
}) => {
   const resultsToAppend = convertSearchToCsvLines({ searchId });
   if (resultsToAppend.length === 0) return; // No need to open our file if there aren't any results

   const csvFile = file.open({ id: fileId });
   for (const csvLine of resultsToAppend) {
      csvFile.appendLine({ value: csvLine });
   }
   csvFile.save();
   
}

const convertSearchToCsvLines = ({ searchId }) => {
   const seachObject = search.load({ id: searchId });
   const pagedSearchData = searchObject.runPaged({ pageSize: 200 }); // pageSize can be any positive integer up to 1,000
   const rows = []
   
   // Use paged search data to get around the limitation of 4,000 results in search.run().each( ... )
   pagedSearchData.pageRanges.forEach( (pageRange) => {
      const searchPage = pagedSearchData.fetch({ index: pageRange.index });
      searchPage.data.forEach( (searchResult) => {
         // now we can map the columns to their values
         const singleRowValuesArray = searchResult.columns.map( (column) => {
            const columnValue = searchResult.getValue( column );
            // wrap the data in quotes
            return `"${columnValue}"`;
         })
         const csvRow = singleRowValuesArray.join(","); //convert the array to CSV
         rows.push( csvRow );
      }
   }
   return rows;
}

});

